# PHP arrays: indexed vs keyed

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, associative-array

I have a method, `fetch_widgets`, that fetches widgets from the (MySQL) database. I pass it an `$options` array so I can selectively add `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses, add/remove columns etc.

For example:

```
    $options = array();
    $options[] = 'include_disabled';
    $options[] = 'include_tag_ids';
    $options['start_date'] = '2011-01-01';
    $options['end_date'] = '2011-01-31';
```

In `fetch_widgets` I check for the options using either:

```
    if(array_key_exists('start_date',$options)) { ... }
```

or:

```
    if(in_array('include_tag_ids',$options)) { ... }
```

depending on whether or not the option is activated just be being present (e.g. `include_disabled`) or has a key and a value (e.g. `end_date`).

I'm running into difficulties because I'm getting strange results from `in_array` when the `$options` array contains keyed and non-keyed values. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What is the strange behavior you are getting?

Comment: Given the above `$options` array I was having `in_array('include_tag_ids',$options)` return false. I seem to have solved it now, not sure what I changed but it's working again

Answer (score 5):

Don't mix/match keyed and non-keyed arrays if you need consistent behavior.

Instead, do something like this:

```
$options = array();
$options['include_disabled'] = true;
$options['include_tag_ids'] = true;
$options['start_date'] = '2011-01-01';
$options['end_date'] = '2011-01-31';
```

Comment: +1 I absolutely agree, though I'd still be interested to see the problem he's experiencing and why.

Comment: I'm curious too.  Based on what he was showing, it should work theoretically, but who knows.

Comment: I'm curious too! If it does crop up again I'll be sure to return.